# Do I need to increase version code of a library module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-module

Consider the following scenario. 
Suppose, I have made an Application named **`ABC`**.

I have also made an Android library module named **`XYZ`** for reusing some code.

I am using module **`XYZ`** in the application **`ABC`** and I have also uploaded that application in the Play Store with versionCode **`1`**

Now I have made some changes in the module **`XYZ`** and some changes in the application **`ABC`**.
For updating that application I am increasing the versionCode to `2` of the application **`ABC`**.

Now my question is do I need to update the versionCode of the module **`XYZ`** also for updating that application to Play Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, upgrading or downgrading of internal module(s) is fully optional to you. There may be a case that due to change in your main project code, you need to downgrade the module version which may be using from some remote location. So if we go with GooglePlay app versioning logic (main app), you cannot downgrade the version but as GooglePlay is not at all concerned about the versioning of internal module(s) of the project so we can downgrade the module(s) version.

Google Play uses the app version code to track internally that user is using any older version or new version. Based on this, the users get notification that a new version of the app is available. So this is your main app specific and no any concerned with the internal module(s) version.

The detail is given below-
[image]

You can get more from [official link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning).

Comment: What about the case where I am publishing my module as an artifact in maven. I usually only increment the version name. Does incrementing version-code give any advantage?

Answer (score 1):

> Now my question is do I need to update the versionCode of the module XYZ also for updating that application to Play Store?

No, you don't even need to change the library version. It's because Play Store only checking for the application version. The library version is up to you because Play Store didn't check for the internal mechanism inside your application.